Type com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzip is defined multiple times
I get the following error when trying to deploy a project, regarding a type which is defined twice:
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Error in obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\243\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzip.class:
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Type com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzip is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\243\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzip.class, obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\244\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzip.class
1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Compilation failed

I tried installing several different NuGet packages in order to solve it without success. I have done the same for other packages that caused similar errors with success, but not this time. Installing Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measure and other relative packages did not solve this particular error.
Here is the full code of the .csproj file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android34.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MyApp</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MyApp</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.my.app</ApplicationId>
        <ApplicationIdGuid>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</ApplicationIdGuid>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android34.0|AnyCPU'">
      <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
      <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
      <AndroidPackageFormat>apk</AndroidPackageFormat>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="google-services.json" />
      <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\values\strings.xml" />
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\my_immage.png" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.Analytics" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.MauiMTAdmob" Version="1.4.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="Plugin.StoreReview" Version="6.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.71" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.71" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks" Version="8.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity.Ktx" Version="1.9.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Collection.Ktx" Version="1.4.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Common" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Runtime" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Service" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModel.Ktx" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.ViewModelSavedState" Version="2.8.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform" Version="3.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite" Version="123.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
      <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
    </ItemGroup>


    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Update="Resources\Resx\AppResources.Designer.cs">
        <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
        <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
        <DependentUpon>AppResources.resx</DependentUpon>
      </Compile>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\Resx\AppResources.resx">
        <Generator>PublicResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
        <LastGenOutput>AppResources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
      </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
        <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="MyPage.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

What the solution would be?

Can you provide the full code of the project's .csproj file? This will help me determine whether the project's packages or TargetFrameworks causes the error.

@ShuowenHe-MSFT
I added the code you asked about.

because error comes frob obj dir, have u tried to delete bin & obj dirs and restoring solution?

More than once... I also tried to Clean and Rebuild the project. Nothing works.

I also have to add that I ran dotnet restore too. It didn't make a difference.

I reproduced your problem.
Then after I added <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity" Version="1.9.1" /> to the project, I cleaned the whole solution, deleted all bin and obj folders then ran a dotnet restore before starting VS and build again.
Finally, The defined multiple times error message no longer appears. You can refer to my steps.

I added Xamarin.AndroidX.Activity and followed your steps, but I'm afraid the problem persists: 1>MSBUILD : java.exe error JAVA0000: Type com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzip is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\243\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzip.class, obj\Debug\net8.0-android34.0\lp\244\jl\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzip.class
Tried at least twice with no luck.

I found a similar case: Type is defined is defined multiple times , and the solution said that it might be caused by adding two libraries to the project, and both used Google service. Does your project include the library?

Which library do you refer too?

I found another solution: you can try to remove the <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform" Version="3.0.0" /> and      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads.Lite" Version="123.0.0" />, then clean and rebuild the project.

I had installed all these packages in order to achieve compatibility of MauiMTAdmob with Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform version 3.0.0.  As the author of MauiMTAdmob have informed me, a new compatible version of his plugin will be soon out. Most probably I'll wait for it. If the release gets delayed then I may try to find a solution to the current issue.

After my test, when I removed the  and , the error disappeared, so the reason is from the dependency package conflicts, Have you tried removing these two packages?

Yes, If I install Xamarin.Google.UserMessagingPlatform version 2.2.0.1 the error goes away. The problem is that with this version I can't make the consent message for the ads to appear. So I tried to upgrade to version 3.0.0 in order to find out it that would solve the problem. The latest version though was incompatible with MauiMTAdmob, so I had to install many different packages to achieve compatibility. Those packages though lead to the current problem during deployment.

Ok, so you can wait for the new compatible version of MauiMTAdmob to be released.

Yes, I think so.

For me too the problem was caused by MauiMTAdmob
